# Troubles with BlankNullSequence in the case of multiplication

Tags: functions, symbolic, pattern-matching

I have some trouble to use the triple underscore notation to use definitions with or without a term. Consider the following toy example

```
f[a___ x]:=1
{f[x],f[2x]}
```

This returns

> {f[x],1}

whereas I would like the $f[x]$ pattern to be matched. I guess it is not recognizing "1" as an empty element. How can I arrange this definition to get {1,1} as an output ?

Comment: Give "a" a default value: `f[a__ : 1  x] := 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[a_. x] := 1
{f[x], f[2 x]}
```

---

> {1, 1}